# How to get all exchange rates for one currency in `forex_conversion` package?

Tags: flutter, forex

I need to get conversion rates for all currencies to EUR. I use `forex_conversion` package.

I tried:

```
final r = await Forex(defaultDestinationCurrency: "EUR").getAllCurrenciesPrices();
r = await Forex(defaultSourceCurrency: "EUR").getAllCurrenciesPrices();
```

But getting rates to USD in the both cases.

Comment: What was the output?

Comment: In general, all currencies are pegged to USD, and it's up to you to get all the conversions and then do the two-part math from X to USD and USD to Y.

Comment: dependencies:
  forex_conversion: ^0.2.5+1

Comment: @TasnuvaTavasumoshin already have this version. It works with USD only. But Randal's solution works